# silverlight compatibility

Tags: silverlight

I am having a look at the silverlight tool to see whether it will usefull in my case. I really like the look that this product gives to the UI, but there are a few considerations that I want to address before using the tool.
What should I consider before starting the development of the site. I mean, can I start building up the server code as if I was creating a asp.net site, o I have to be carefull the way I start
Does silverlight work ok on all the web browsers available; this is very important for me, as my site should be working on any browser.
This product is unknown to me, so any guides that you might give me will be very helpfull

Many thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the following link which is a Q&A from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/faq/

Also learn more at www.silverlight.net

It is compatible with all major browsers but a the silverlight plug-in does need to be installed.  Which comes default now with windows updates.  Although Sliverlight runs in a asp.net site, I would think it would be beneficial to learn Silverlight before starting your asp.net site.